# Java Instrumentation/JavassistHelper example code does not work

Tags: java, instrumentation

I am trying to build and run my own version of the example in [this tutorial](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/04/24/add-logging-at-class-load-time-with-instrumentation.html)

I made an eclipse project that runs the HelloWorld class with instrumentation. If I use the loggeragent.jar I downloaded from the link at the bottom of that page, it works. But if I build loggeragent.jar (from the same source code), it throws an exception in method.insertBefore():

**Could not instrument  HelloWorld,  exception : [source error] syntax error near "r($1)+"));"**

The signature string that it tries to insert is, according to the debugger:

**"main("  + "args" + "="+ org.slf4j.instrumentation.ToStringHelper.render($1)+")"**

Now, I needed to make a few changes to some imports to get the code to build. In particular, I needed to add import org.slf4j.instrumentation.JavassistHelper;.  So it could be that the two jars are not using the same version of JavaassistHelper, but I can't find another version.

Any idea why this doesn't work? Also, could you explain what JavaassistHelper does, or point me to a manual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the issue is - there is a error in the example code - it says

```
method.insertBefore(ifLog + "_log.info(\">> " + signature + ");");
```

Where it should say

```
method.insertBefore(ifLog + "_log.info(\">> " + signature + "\");");
```

(missing a \" towards the end).